# Add another data to json array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, while-loop

I'm trying to create a JSON array with loop, I stored languages name in database and retrieving from query, after that I need to convert it into this format

```
$arrayName = array('lang-1' => null , 'lang-2' => null, ..... ,'lang-n' => null );
```

how can I achieve that

PHP code is like this

```
include_once "inc/init.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arrayName = array();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `medium`");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
array_push($arrayName, $data['medium']);
}
echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

im getting in this format

```
[
 "Kannada",
 "Telugu",
 "Tamil",
 "Urdu",
 "Spanish",
 "Arabian"
]
```

im trying pushing value but im not getting in that format, please help me

Thank you

Comment: And what format do you get? How does your table structure looks like?

Comment: I need to see your table structure to write you an answer for your issue.

Comment: database table?
it is having only 2 columns.  id and language columns

Comment: i need language name as key n value is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments I'm asuming that `$data['language']` represents a name of your language. Then you can achieve your goal by the following code:

```
include_once "inc/init.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arrayName = array();
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `medium`");

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $arrayName[$data['language']] = null; // $array[$key] = $value
}

echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

Comment: yes, thank you, in this format only i wanted that array,

Answer (score 1):

using array_push you will get the same result

```
include_once "inc/init.php";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$arrayName = array();
$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `medium`");
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
array_push($arrayName,$data['language ']);

}
$arrayName=array_fill_keys($arrayName, 'null'); 
echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

Comment: in this case i'll get all languages in different array object, like **[{lang-1}, {lang-2}....{lang-n}]** this

Comment: above answer is solved my question, anyway thank you for replay

Comment: @Rak_code right! please see now it will work for you

Comment: Yeah. It is also working fine. :) tq tq for your answer

Comment: it's my pleasure!